# Add values with same date in Php

Tags: php

I want to add values with same date. However, I'm confused on how to implement it to my code. The output of code below gets the total minutes together with its date. Can someone help me or give some advice with this?

Here's my code:

```
    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){

        if(!empty($row3['time_outAM'])){
            $attend_timeoutfirst = date("H:i:s", strtotime($row3['time_outAM']));
            if($sched_timeoutfirst > $attend_timeoutfirst ){
                $start = strtotime($attend_timeoutfirst);
                $stop = strtotime($sched_timeoutfirst);
                $diff = ($stop - $start);
                echo  $total1 = abs($diff/60);  
                echo "<br>";
                echo $date = $row3['date'];
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
        if(!empty($row3['time_outPM'])){
            $attend_timeoutsec = date("H:i:s", strtotime($row3['time_outPM']));
            if($sched_timeoutsec > $attend_timeoutsec){
                $start = strtotime($attend_timeoutsec);
                $stop = strtotime($sched_timeoutsec);
                $diff = ($stop - $start);
                echo $total2 = abs($diff/60);  
                echo "<br>";
                echo $date1 = $row3['date'];
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Code Output:

```
30
2022-05-03
30
2022-05-04
10
2022-05-04
120
2022-05-09
70
2022-05-09
```

Expected Output:

```
30
2022-05-03
40
2022-05-04
190
2022-05-09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sum value of date outside `for loop`

```
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    $total1 = 0;
    $total2 = 0;
    $date = '';
    $date1 = '';
    if(!empty($row3['time_outAM'])){
        $attend_timeoutfirst = date("H:i:s", strtotime($row3['time_outAM']));
        if($sched_timeoutfirst > $attend_timeoutfirst ){
            $start = strtotime($attend_timeoutfirst);
            $stop = strtotime($sched_timeoutfirst);
            $diff = ($stop - $start);
            $total1 = abs($diff/60); 
            $date = $row3['date'];
        }
    }
    if(!empty($row3['time_outPM'])){
        $attend_timeoutsec = date("H:i:s", strtotime($row3['time_outPM']));
        if($sched_timeoutsec > $attend_timeoutsec){
            $start = strtotime($attend_timeoutsec);
            $stop = strtotime($sched_timeoutsec);
            $diff = ($stop - $start);
            $total2 = abs($diff/60);  
            $date1 = $row3['date'];
        }
    }
    if($date == $date1){
        echo  $total1 +  $total2;  
        echo "<br>";
        echo $date;
        echo "<br>";
    }else{
        echo  $total1;  
        echo "<br>";
        echo $date;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I remove the zero values? It takes much space.